# Problem to login proxy with gitkraken and git

Tags: git, proxy, gitkraken

When I perform a push / pull / fetch operation, gitkraken with the classic configuration http://[user]:[password]@[proxyaddr]:[port] returns the error:

```
Pull Failed: failed to get server certificate: The handle is in the 
wrong state for the requested operation
```

while setting the proxy with user and domain as [http://[domain]\[user]:[password]@[proxyaddr]:[port]](http://[domain]%5C[user]:[password]@[proxyaddr]:[port]) gitkraken returns the error:

```
Pull Failed: malformed URL http://[domain]\\[user]:   
[password]@[proxyaddr]:[port]
```

With git client from the command line I have no problem. How can I solve it?

I tried also without proxy because both the PC and the login user are in the domain

OS Windows Server 2012 R2
Gitkraken version: 6.0.1

thank you so much
regards

Comment: I am not aware the gitkraken supports that sort of URL formatting. I recommend reaching out to them directly - they are usually very fast with support. Would it work better to use an ssh url in the interim?

Comment: @BenW I think so since the git client establishes the communication. I will try as you advised me

Comment: Does it work if you write the `domain\user` component as `domain%5Cuser` instead (that is, replace the backslash with `%5C`)? Unescaped backslashes aren't allowed in the userinfo portion of a URL.

Comment: @bk2204 I tried but it doesn't work. without domain, from the command line, the proxy returns a nice 407

Comment: I solved by installing version 6.0.0 of gitkraken